# sqlalchemy added new column and `UndefinedColumn` Error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am inserting data to a remote postgres db and recently added a new column to one of the tables and now I'm getting this error inserting new data into the table with new column

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "build_name" of relation "DryRun" does not exist
LINE 1: ...tance_id, profile_name, host_box, default_config, build_name...
```

I tried what I found online such as setting `nullable=True` or giving it a default value `default='Unknown'`, but still hitting the same error.

Here's my `DryRun` model.

```
class DryRun(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DryRun'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    instance_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    profile_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    host_box = Column(String, nullable=False)
    default_config = Column(JSON, nullable=False)
    build_name = Column(String, nullable=True)
```

Comment: The issue is that now the object differs from what's in the database. You can run an ALTER TABLE command to add the column within the command-line tool psql, or using the pgadmin GUI. And if you're anticipating more such changes, consider reading about migrations which are supported by some other modules; for instance, alembic: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was originally posted as a comment.

The issue is that now the object differs from what's in the database. You can run an ALTER TABLE command to add the column within the command-line tool psql, or using the pgadmin GUI. And if you're anticipating more such changes, consider reading about migrations which are supported by some other modules; for instance, alembic: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/

For just one column addition, migrations most likely don't make sense though. Here's an example of an ALTER TABLE command for your use-case:

```
# run this command to get to a text-based interface to your Postgres database
$ psql

# alter table command for your use-case:
ALTER TABLE "DryRun" ADD COLUMN build_name VARCHAR;
```